# RavenDB: Windows user credentials not sufficient for write access

Tags: authentication, ravendb

I'm trying to use the RavenDB server web/silverlight UI to create databases and test data, and am being asked for a username/password. This is fine, and the documentation on http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/5/ravendb-in-practice-part-1-an-introduction-to-ravendb says that I should use my Windows credentials:

> Be default RavenDB allow anonymous access only for read requests (HTTP GET), and since we creating data, we need to specify a username and password. You can control this by changing the AnonymousAccess setting in the server configuration file.
>
> Enter your username and password of your Windows account and a sample data will be generated for you.

However the dialog reappears instantly. A few tries later and it fails with an authorisation error.

I'm using the Raven Silverlight client through Google Chrome Windows XP Home SP3, and haven't changed RavenDB's settings (I want it to work with authentication, rather than dodging the issue).

Comment: Which browser are you using, IE, Chrome?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: Trying putting your username as DOMAIN\User

Comment: [Answer in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616356/ravendb-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-403-forbidden) helped me

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure you give user permissions to read/write in the directory where raven is installed.

2) Make sure that you have      set in web.config

3) Check this thread [RavenDB Network Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672237/ravendb-network-access)