# RavenDB Network Access

Tags: ravendb

I'm having a difficult time finding information on how to get RavenDB to work on a network. Within the same network, I can have an instance of my app running, and it will show data from my RavenDB. However, when I try to write data, I get a 401 Unauthorized exception.

What is the correct way to set up a RavenDB to be accessed over the network?

Right now, I have this in *Raven.Server.exe.config*, which is just a short-term solution:

```xml
<add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="All" />
```

What I don't understand, is that the RavenDB web site says to use something like this:

```xml
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="RavenDb" 
       connectionString="Url=http://serverName:8080;user=user;password=password"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Ok, that's great for the application that's running, but how do I set the RavenDB server to allow that user and password? Is that just the wrong way to do it (somehow setting the RavenDB config file to allow those credentials)? If that's wrong, how am I supposed to define credentials on the server side?

Edit: Here are my attempts and results:

I'm running RavenDB by double-clicking Raven.Server.exe.

**Scenario 1**

Client app.Config:

```xml
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="RavenDb" connectionString="Url = http://server:8080;domain=Xx;user=Xx\user;password=pw"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

DocumentStore Setup:

```
DocumentStore documentStore = new DocumentStore();
documentStore.ConnectionStringName = "RavenDb";
documentStore.Initialize();
```

Save Operation:

```
Session.Store(objectToSave);
```

Result:
"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

**Scenario 2**

Client app.config:

```xml
<add key="databaseUrl" value="http://server:8080"/>
```

DocumentStore Setup:

```
string databaseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["databaseUrl"];            
DocumentStore documentStore = new DocumentStore();
documentStore.Url = databaseUrl;
documentStore.Initialize();
```

Save Operation:

```
Session.Store(objectToSave);
```

Result:
"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."
Inner exception: "The target principal name is incorrect"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a local user on the machine RavenDB runs on and use any credentials you'd like. Then assign read/write permissions for the /Data directory (and the /Tenants directory if needed) to this user.

If you're running RavenDB as a service or standalone application, remote auth should work with the (windows)users credentials. If you're running on IIS, please make sure you have Windows Authentication enabled (disabled by default!).

Comment: Ahhhhh... so it's just authorization to the Data folder. I don't need to specify the user in the server config. The client connections can specify the user in the config, and as long as that user has access to the Data folder... I'll try that.

Comment: Tried two approaches. See scenarios/edits above. What am I missing?

Comment: Your first scenario should work. Just tried it on two machines of mine. _BUT_ it did not work with domain users. Instead I needed to create a local user and assign permissions accordingly. As username on the client I supplied "machineName\Username" - didn't need to supply the domainname additionally.

Comment: I just kept trying different things, over and over again, and it *finally* just worked. I actually had to specify the machine name as the domain in the connection string. This is bogus/temporary data, so I don't mind showing the connection string that just worked: <add name="RavenDb" connectionString="Url=http://server1:8080;domain=server1;user=PrestoDatabaseUser;password=xyz123"/>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6271/discussion-between-bob-horn-and-daniel-lang)

Comment: According to Ayende, setting permissions at the Data folder level does not do anything since the server does not impersonate the authenticated user when accessing the data files. Here is the link: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ravendb/nDtRXQdFVmY

Answer (score 4):

For me, I had to add domain to the connection string on the prod machine, but NOT when accessing that same machine remotely... I dunno.

Of note: I created a windows user named RAVENDB, and assigned it full permissions to the data directory.

so my connection string that worked fine remotely was

```
<add name="raven" connectionString="Url=http://myserver.com:8080;user=RAVENDB;password=PASS" />
```

whereas on the actual server, i had to use

```
<add name="raven" connectionString="Url=http://myserver:8080;DOMAIN=MYSERVERNAME;user=RAVENDB;password=PASS" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Bob,
By default, RavenDB uses Windows authentication. So if you create the user on the server machine, it would accept it.
The alternative is to define ravendb specific users, but many people just use Windows Auth.

Comment: Tried two approaches. See scenarios/edits above. What am I missing?