# RavenDb - The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, ravendb

When I try to create a <strike>database</strike> people collection on RavenDb, I get the following error:

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

I hots the Raven on IIS and I am not sure what is going on. On the raven Management Studio, when I try to create a database, I get the below result:

> Could not authenticate against server
>
> Message: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. Uri:
>   /databases?database=Default Server Uri:
>   http://localhost:8888/docs/Raven/Databases/People
>
> -- Error Information -- System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.    at
>   System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at System.Func`2.Invoke(T arg)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
>   iar, Func`2 endMethod, TaskCompletionSource`1 tcs)

When I looked into this with process monitor, I see that I am getting bunch of not found errors:

[image]

Under `C:\Utils\RavenDB\Web` directory, there are **Bin** and **Data** folders, nothing more. <strike>Should I create the necessary folders by myself?</strike> I created the docs folder but nothing changed. Still having problems.

Any thoughts?

**Edit:**

Tried with fiddler on Raven Management Studio by creating a document:

**Request:**

> PUT http://localhost:1786/docs/People HTTP/1.1
>
> Accept: */*
>
> Accept-Language: en-US
>
> Referer: http://localhost:1786/silverlight/Raven.Studio.xap
>
> Content-Length: 24
>
> Accept-Encoding: identity
>
> If-None-Match: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
>
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7
>   (KHTML, like Gecko)  Chrome/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7
>
> Host: localhost:1786
>
> Connection: Keep-Alive
>
> Pragma: no-cache
>
> {
>
> "Name": "..."
>
> }

**Response:**

> HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
>
> Cache-Control: private
>
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
>
> X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>
> X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>
> Date: Thu, 08 Mar 2012 12:33:22 GMT
>
> Content-Length: 0

Comment: Can you check what is going on through Fiddler?

Comment: @AyendeRahien looked into that, edited the question with that information.

Comment: I have encountered the same issue, with pretty much the same fiddler output (bar the host/port etc)

Comment: Update: My issue was resolved by this config value: <add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="Get"/> changed to <add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="All"/>, despite the fact I have a service account set up just for Raven that is configured in IIS (with the relevant folder permissions). Try setting that value in the web.config and post your results

Comment: @jonvd That fixed it for me as well. You should put this as an answer

Comment: @JonVD yep, this is the answer. Ayende tweeted that as well. Put it as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This was answered in the comments, however I'll post it here for posterity.

The issue is resolved by changing the web.config value:

```
<add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="Get"/>
```

To:

```
<add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="All"/>
```

[Here](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/deployment/as-iis-application) is the link to the config page that explains each of the options. Be aware that this option will in fact turn off authentication, if you wish to run with authentication you will need the 'Get' or 'None' setting and you will also need to make sure Windows Authentication is installed (IIS 7.5) and enabled on the Raven IIS Application.

Comment: the correct thing to do is enable windows auth for the iis site, make a user, give that user permissions on the db folder, and use that user from your client app.

Comment: There are also a few other steps to follow to use IIS and Raven together happily, these can be found in the link above.